# Amazon AWS Kali - Metasploit

Tags: metasploit, kali-linux, aws

I'm using the Amazon marketplace Kali and I'm trying to test CVE-2017-0199 to see if my proxy settings to block application/hta content are working.

There is a module in metasploit that allows me to test this.

exploits/windows/fileformat/office_word_hta (or something like that)

However i need to set the reverse shell LHOST = External IP, for the payload to do a reverse callback to the kali box.
At the moment it will only allow me to set the LHOST = internal IP (172.X.X.X).

Everytime i try to set the LHOST = external IP or domain name pointing to the external IP i get bind error and it wont let me.
I am also running metasploit as root.
There are no apache2 instances running on it.

I am owner of both the AWS instance and the endpoint i am testing on.

Is this an amazon restriction?
Can anyone advise on this please?

Without me being able to set the payload to my external AWS IP, the payload will never call back to the AWS metasploit listener..

Comment: "it will only allow me" - how does it limit you? Can you show the bind error (the text, not a screenshot)

Comment: Are you able to map ports from public ip to the Kali machine? if yes, is what you need to do.

Comment: is this what you are talking about: https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/forum/metasploit-error-handler-failed-bind-0165058/

Comment: no i am using the AWS as the "attacker" and my windows box as the "victim" and making sure the traffic goes external from my window box out via proxy to internet to AWS attacker, i am testing a proxy rule.

But AWS wont allow me to set external ip as payload callback address

Answer (score 1):

AWS has very specific rules in place to help prevent their boxes from being abused. Running Kali or streaming to an ec2 instance is very restricted if not impossible. I don't know exactly how they are enforcing these rules (firewall rules on their end, something in their Virtual Machine Setup, etc), but if you are trying to test a vulnerability on a AWS box I doubt you'll have any luck.